# What does it mean to be the 'voice of reason' in a group?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What role does the 'voice of reason' play in the group?

Comment: Being unreasonable does not necessarily mean being emotional.

Comment: There is another sense of _Reason_, however, which made Neal Stephenson use it as the name for his fictional [railgun in _Snow Crash_](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1746). _Ratio_ is Latin for 'reason', and Louis XIV had the Latin phrase _Ultima Ratio Regum_ 'The Final Argument of Kings' cast into his cannon. [Cannon like these](http://dngrs.tumblr.com/post/133776206256/ultima-ratio-regum-the-last-argument-of-kings) are another powerful metaphor available for 'the voice of reason'.

Comment: ... and being reasonable does not necessarily mean being unemotional. There appears to have been a bit of kerfuffle over the phrase during the Age of Enlightenment as secularists tried to wrest the phrase from the Church. The voice of reason is someone who attempts to demystify the issue at hand.

Answer (score 4):

It is a saying used in contrast to an emotional approach:

[Reason](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reason):

> - the ​ability of a ​healthy ​mind to ​think and make ​judgments, ​especially ​based on ​practical ​facts. (Cambridge Dictionary)

If you are thinking about making risky investments, "the voice of reason" will suggest not to do that and be very careful.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20voice%20of%20reason&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20voice%20of%20reason%3B%2Cc0): *the voice of reason*

Answer (score 1):

A person with a voice of reason is someone who gives good and meaningful advice to avoid bad consequences

Answer (score 1):

> The voice of reason is the person who tries to get the group to adopt decisions using evidence and logic. [...] – [deadrat](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/125330/deadrat) Dec 17 '15 at 9:33

Answer (score 1):

The voice of reason is one person using clear, practical and logical reasons to convince another person to give up on their dreams.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree. I believe the voice of reason is just giving advice to support both sides so that the person can make a good sound decision based on facts, rather than emotional thinking. I have been told I am the voice of reason, I reserve judgement and support all my friends and families dreams  percent. However, if there is another angle to this decision, I present what I know about the subject giving others another view. Never would I steal anyone's hopes and/or dreams, ever.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. All of the above is your own opinion which, on Stack Exchange generally, and on EL&U particularly, is off-topic.